# How to customize EntityType option text?

Tags: forms, symfony, query-builder

I would like to display selection with options from DB. In this case, I am using `EntityType` with `query_builder`:

```
$builder
    ->add('internships', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'IndexBundle\Entity\Internship',
        'property' => 'id',
        'empty_value' => 'Choose',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($trainee) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('i')
                ->where('i.trainee = :trainee')
                ->andWhere('i.state = :state')
                ->setParameter('trainee', $trainee)
                ->setParameter('state', 'unverified');
        },
        'constraints' => array(
            new NotBlank(array(
                'message' => 'choice.not.blank'
            ))
        )
    ))
```

Now all is fine. I get `select` element with necessary options within with text of `id` value.

```
<select>
    <option value="id">id</option>
    ...
</select>
```

How do I customize it?

For example I would like it to be combination of `id` and `type` table columns:

```
<select>
    <option value="id">#id (type)</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Comment: You are looking for the `choice_label` option for the formtype. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`choice_label`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label) option to customize your options.
You can either pass a function to retrieve the text you want, or you can add a getter to your entity if you reuse it at another place.

**With a function:**

```
$builder
    ->add('internships', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'IndexBundle\Entity\Internship',
        'property' => 'id',
        'empty_value' => 'Choose',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($trainee) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('i')
                ->where('i.trainee = :trainee')
                ->andWhere('i.state = :state')
                ->setParameter('trainee', $trainee)
                ->setParameter('state', 'unverified');
        },
        'choice_label' => function ($internship) {
            return '#'.$internship->getId().' ('.$internship->getType().')';
        },
        'constraints' => array(
            new NotBlank(array(
                'message' => 'choice.not.blank'
            ))
        )
    ))
```

**With a getter:**

```
$builder
    ->add('internships', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'IndexBundle\Entity\Internship',
        'property' => 'id',
        'empty_value' => 'Choose',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($trainee) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('i')
                ->where('i.trainee = :trainee')
                ->andWhere('i.state = :state')
                ->setParameter('trainee', $trainee)
                ->setParameter('state', 'unverified');
        },
        'choice_label' => 'idAndType',
        'constraints' => array(
            new NotBlank(array(
                'message' => 'choice.not.blank'
            ))
        )
    ))
```

<kbd>Internship.php</kbd>:

```
Class Internship
{
    //...
    public function getIdAndType()
    {
        return '#'.$this->id.' ('.$this->type.')';
    }
}
```

**Note:**
For older Symfony versions (<= 2.6), this option was named [`property`](http://symfony.com/doc/2.5/reference/forms/types/entity.html#property) and use something supported by the [PropertyAccessor component](http://symfony.com/doc/2.5/components/property_access/introduction.html), so you can't use a function, only a getter for it.